# No output on consolte after building Assember project im MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

I found a piece of code that i tried to build using MASM on Windows. Building does not cause any errors but I can't find out whether it's a code or MASM problem because I am totally new to this topic.

Please tell me why the program prints nothing on the console. Thank you.

**(1) Source Code**

```
;==============================================================
  .386
  .model flat,stdcall
  option casemap:none
;==============================================================

 include \masm32\include\windows.inc
 include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
 include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc

 includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
 includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data
 szLine db 80 DUP("="),0
 szCaption db "Mein erstes Consolen Programm:",10,0
 szEingabe db "Bitte eine Zahl eingeben:",0
 szAusgabe db "Deine Zahl:",0
 Zahl      db 20 DUP(0)
.code

start:
 push offset szLine
 call StdOut
 push offset szCaption
 call StdOut
 push offset szLine
 call StdOut
 push offset szEingabe
 call StdOut
 push 20
 push offset Zahl
 call StdIn
 push offset szAusgabe
 call StdOut
 push offset Zahl
 call StdOut

 push 0
 push 0
 call StdIn
 push 0
 call ExitProcess
end start
```

**(2) Build result**

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: C:\1.asm

***********
ASCII build
***********

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.

 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is DEF0-6193

 Directory of C:\

11.11.2013  14:24               911 1.asm
11.11.2013  14:37             2.560 1.exe
11.11.2013  14:37             1.027 1.obj
               3 File(s)          4.498 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  33.380.294.656 bytes free
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**(3) Output**

When I run the exe-file on the console it shows nothing.

```
C:\Users\LOL>c:\1.exe

C:\Users\LOL>
```

**(4) Expected result**

At least a bit of output. ("=" etc.)

Comment: I am such a ------. This is my first time using ASM/MASM. The ***solution*** is to use the "Console build All" option and not the simple "Build all" feature. Sorry :(

Comment: Works fine for me (except that it crashes when I pressed Return after the "Deine Zahl" message). Built using `ml /c /coff test.asm` / `link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE test.obj`

Comment: Stefan, now that you know the answer you should post the answer and accept it, so this doesn't clutter the "unanswered questions". thanks!

Comment: Sadly, I cannot accept my own answer.

Comment: You have to add your answer first. I think [so] requires you to wait a day before you can post an answer.

Comment: I agree with @hjpotter92, you should post your results as an answer.